# How to connect to a local Oracle database inside a virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Oracle database inside a virtual machine and I want to connect to it through data factory. I have already created the self-hosted integration but I do not know what parameter to pass to the host when I create the Linked Service to be able to make the connection. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the host name you have to put localhost